# How to execute function on form submit callback

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, the problem is that `#modalLoad` 
appears and disappears in the same second, even form.submit () takes 1 minute.

```
//show the div of loading
$('#modalLoad').modal('show');

// submit 
form.submit(); //One minute of processing

//hide the div of loading 
$('#modalLoad').modal('hide');
```

i want hide the `#modalLoad` Only after the `form.submit();` callback, can I do that?

**EDIT:**

I just want to do  `$('#modalLoad').modal('hide');` on the exacly moment of `form.submit();` finish.
I used:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#modalLoad').modal('hide');
}, 10000);
```

for wait +- 1 minute, but I think have a better way. Didn't?

Comment: "Only after the callback" - Well, that's exactly the issue here - you don't *have* a callback.

Comment: What does your form submit to? It will probably reload the page anyway.

Comment: are you doing an ajax call ?

Comment: @SLaks this form submit make a download of a PDF file and NOT reload the page

Comment: That is probably impossible.

Comment: @karthick, i already tried do this with ajax, but ajax dont make the Download of PDF file

Comment: Can you recreate your behavior in fiddle and post there

Comment: @Santi i already set the response Header in java.  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + getNomeArquivo() + ".pdf\"");

Comment: How are you implementing the Java method into your JavaScript? Feels like I'm pulling teeth here - can you just edit your question to be a **[Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**?

Comment: In java i use doPost:
`protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  
  try {
   execPDF(request, response);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }`

Comment: But how are you invoking that from JavaScript? There needs to be some coordination here between your JS and your Java, and that JS event is going to need a callback.

Comment: `var form = document.createElement ('form'); Form.setAttribute ('id', 'formPDF'); Formulario.method = 'POST'; Formulario.action = 'ExportarPDF'; 
//show the div of loading
$('#modalLoad').modal('show');

// submit 
form.submit(); //One minute of processing

//hide the div of loading 
$('#modalLoad').modal('hide');` Just that man, very simple, and work fine, the only problem is the LOADING DIV

Comment: What is `ExportarPDF`? Where are you handling this form action?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant code. Also note that despite your protestations otherwise, the browser does do a redirect; it's just that it redirects to a URL that has a header which causes a PDF to download rather than an HTML page.

Comment: @Santi, `ExportarPDF` is the name of my Servlet, where is made the PDF and flush them

Comment: Rather than searching for how to get the response of a form submit, you should be searching *"How to get response from java servlet using javascript"* or something of the sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve this problem using this Jquery plugin: http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/

```
        //show the div of loading   
        $('#modalPDF').modal('show');

         //Do the download of file.
         $.fileDownload($('#form').prop('action'), {
            httpMethod: "POST",
            data: $('#form').serialize()
         }).done(function () {

            //hide the div of loading after PDF process
            $('#modalPDF').modal('hide');

         })
         .fail(function () { 

            alert('error during PDF generation!')

         });
```